# How do I get percentage from 100 to 4.65 in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show the user deductible amount in the input field.

Let's just say I have one input field where the user put a number like 100 and I want to find out and 4.65 of 100 and show the rest amount to the other input field.

[You will understand by seeing this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdWM4.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var amount = 0, discount = 0;
      amount = prompt("Purchase amount", "Enter the amount");
      if (amount < 100) {
        document.write("Sorry no discount");
      }
      if ((amount >= 100) && (amount <= 300)) {
        discount = 4.65;
      }
      amount = amount-((amount*discount)/100);
      if(discount > 0) {
        document.write("Discount  " + discount + "  %");
      }document.write("<br/> The Amount to be Paid  " + amount);
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "and I want to find out and 4.65"  huh?  And you want to find out what?  I don't understand that sentence.

Comment: Can you please add some minimum code that shows the effort you have put in trying to solve it? Also, do you mean to calculate the referral final price from the percentage computed from `myPrice * (comissionPercent - 4.65)  / 100`?

Comment: axelduch I'm not JS person but yes I did some work on that.

Comment: Syed, I'd suggest adding that code to your answer with an edit. This would make it much easier for people to find it. Also, don't forget to format by highlighting the code and clicking the "{}" button.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Lewis

Comment: This question is getting nicer, thanks for the updates OP

Answer (score 1):

Simply check for a change event on the total and percentage inputs and update the remainder/referral inputs based on their values.

```js
// cache the elements
const $total = $('#total');
const $percentage = $('#percentage');
const $remainder = $('#remainder');
const $referral = $('#referral');

// if the total or percentage values change call `handleChange`
$(document).on('change', '#total, #percentage', handleChange);

function handleChange() {

  // grab the input values and coerce them to numbers
  // perform the calcuation
  const perc = (+$percentage.val() / +$total.val()) * 100;

  // update the other inputs
  $remainder.val(+$total.val() - perc);
  $referral.val(perc);
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

label {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input id="total">Total</label>
<label><input value="0" id="percentage">%</label>
<label><input id="remainder">Remainder</label>
<label><input id="referral">Referral</label>
```